# Getting username of logged in user in django

Tags: python, django, authentication

I am new to Django and I just want to find a way to get the username of a logged in user and use it to get the boards of the user. I may have done the models wrong by adding another user model but I would like some help in getting the user's username. Here is my views file:

```
    from django.shortcuts import render
from django.urls import reverse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate,login
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import board_member,user
# Create your views here.

def index(request):
# Login form submitted?
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        if username and password:
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            # Login succeeded
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('login_success'))
        # Login failed
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('login_fail'))
    return render(request, 'Boards/login.html')

def login_success(request):
    return render(request, 'Boards/Homepage.html')

def getboards(request):
    username = request.user.get_username()
    boards = []
    for Memberships in board_member.objects.all():
        if username == Memberships.user.username:
            boards.append(Memberships.board)
    return render(request, 'Boards/Homepage.html', {'boards': boards, 'username':username})

def login_fail(request):
    return render(request, 'login_fail.html')
```

and this is my models file:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

class board(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return (self.name)

class user(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    boards = models.ManyToManyField(
        board, through='board_member', related_name="members")

    def __str__(self):
        return(self.username)


class list(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    board = models.ForeignKey(
        board, related_name="lists", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class board_member(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        user, related_name="memberships", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    board = models.ForeignKey(
        board, related_name="memberships", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    access = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return ("%s is %s in board %s" % (self.user, self.access, self.board))


class card(models.Model):
    list = models.ForeignKey(list, related_name="cards",
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    due = models.DateField()
    flag = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

Comment: I don't understand why you have a separate user model here. Remove that and use the built-in one.

Answer (score 2):

Normally to get the username of logged in user you do

`username = request.user.username.`
within the view itself.

However I am not sure why  you created another user model. I guess you are trying to extend the existing auth user model.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to implement [django custom user model](https://learnbatta.com/blog/using-custom-user-model-in-django-23/) and add extra field `boards`.
After in views you can get all boards like

```
request.user.boards.all()
```